# Migrate mongodb to redis

Tags: mongodb, migration, redis

I have a small mongodb database that I want to migrate to a redis store. I do not want to use them in conjunction with the other, unless the overhead is so small it's insignificant.

How can I go about doing this? I found very little information on this subject.

Comment: How big is your data? Is it sharded?

Comment: Nope, just a single small 10MB database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your database is just 10MB I would recommend look at language [drivers for mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) and [redis](http://redis.io/clients). Mongo records are simple JSON and redis has support for hashmaps, sets and lists. I guess you really won't be having any problem migrating for 10MB database. You really don't need any serious solution to migrate. A simple iteration over mongo collection would do your work in maybe a fraction of a second.

Comment: How would the data remap? Would all of my json objects just be directly converted to hashes? Can I nest a set (array) in a hash? Here's a look at my schema. https://gist.github.com/19f8dd700682c4debac7

Comment: Actually I am new to node. I am a python developer and I am aware of how this could be done using pymongo. Pymongo returns data in python native datastructure (list and dictionaries) which could be easily mapped to redis. Just simply do something like=> for elem in db.collection.find({}): // Map to redis object